# Adding Order By Month to $selector AdWords API PHP lib V201705

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Very "green" when dealing with the AdWords API. Could someone assist in how to use ORDER BY .. specifically ORDER BY 'Month'?

```
public static function runExample(AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
  AdWordsSessionBuilder $sessionBuilder, $reportDir) {
// Construct an API session for the client customer ID specified in the
// configuration file.
$session = $sessionBuilder->build();

// Create selector.
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->setFields(['Month', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Ctr', 'AverageCpc', 'AveragePosition', 'Cost', 'Conversions', 'CostPerConversion', 'ConversionRate', 'SearchImpressionShare']);

$From = date('Ym01', strtotime("-5 months"));
$To = date('Ymt', strtotime("-0 months"));

$selector->setDateRange(new DateRange($From, $To));



// Use a predicate to filter out paused criteria (this is optional).
//$selector->setPredicates([
    //new Predicate('Impressions', PredicateOperator::GREATER_THAN, [1000]),
    //new Predicate('CampaignName', PredicateOperator::CONTAINS, ['Branded'])
    //]);

// Create report definition.
$reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
$reportDefinition->setSelector($selector);
$reportDefinition->setReportName('MOM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT');
$reportDefinition->setDateRangeType(
    ReportDefinitionDateRangeType::CUSTOM_DATE);
$reportDefinition->setReportType(
    ReportDefinitionReportType::ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT);
$reportDefinition->setDownloadFormat(DownloadFormat::CSV);

$customerIds = self::getAllManagedCustomerIds($adWordsServices, $session);
printf("Downloading reports for %d managed customers.\n",
    count($customerIds));
```

I am assuming ORDER BY goes inside of the selector?

Answer (score 0):

I was helped on another forum....see below.

```
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\SortOrder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201705\cm\OrderBy;
.
.
$selector->setOrdering([new OrderBy('Name', SortOrder::ASCENDING)]); //sort by 
Name
```